# Pytorch netwrok with variable number of hidden layers

Tags: pytorch

I want to create a class that creates a simple network with X fully connected layers, where X is an input given by the user. I tried this using the setattr/getattr but for some reason is not working.

```py
class MLP(nn.Module):
      def __init__(self,in_size, out_size,n_layers, hidden_size):
        super(MLP,self).__init__()
        self.n_layers=n_layers

        for i in range(n_layers):
            if i==0:
                layer_in_size = in_size
            else:
                layer_in_size = hidden_size

            if i==(n_layers-1):
                layer_out_size = out_size
            else:
                layer_out_size = hidden_size

            setattr(self,'dense_{}'.format(i), nn.Linear(layer_in_size,layer_out_size))

        def forward(self,x):
            out = x
            for i in range(self.n_layers):
                if i==(self.n_layers-1):
                    out = getattr(self,'dense_{}'.format(i),out)
                else:
                    out = F.relu(getattr(self,'dense_{}'.format(i),out))

            return out
```

This is the error im getting when trying a forward pass with the net:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LftI.png)

Some insights of what's the issue will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a problem with forward implementation with the mod2 function. Try the [pytorch functions](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/torch.html?highlight=mod#torch.fmod) (`torch.fmod` and `torch.remainder`) or if you don't need the backprop capabilities try to do `.detach()` before the mod2 function.